# Rails debug method only outputs !binary values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I have scoured the internet as best I can for this problem, but I am completely shafted by the keyword !binary as search engines (including stackoverflow's internal search!) strip the exclamation mark.

I am working through the Rails tuorial at http://ruby.railstutorial.org - whcih has for the most part been an excellent resource. One of the useful things that I have at the bottom of my application.html.erb page is:

```
<%= dump(params) %>
```

I am told that a particular scenario should output the following:

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
commit: Sign in
session: !ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  password: ""
  email: ""
authenticity_token: BlO65PA1oS5vqrv591dt9B22HGSWW0HbBtoHKbBKYDQ=
action: create
controller: sessions
```

Instead I get the following:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
!binary "dXRmOA==": ✓
!binary "YXV0aGVudGljaXR5X3Rva2Vu": ItPS/PZ+avYOGD2ckict1urJpatw1HinrVyk385/Yt8=
!binary "c2Vzc2lvbg==": !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  !binary "dXNlcm5hbWU=": ''
  !binary "cGFzc3dvcmQ=": ''
!binary "Y29tbWl0": Sign in
action: create
controller: sessions
```

Which is far less helpful.

I am assuming that rails has the option of outputting data as it is in memory (i.e. binary form) or it can decode the data and display it in plain text.

I am obviously getting the correct data, just in the wrong form.

The question is how do I get the plain text version?

The second question is why the heck does a site like stackoverflow not have a mechanism to include special characters in searches? Fundamental Fail IMO

Comment: Also, calling debug() onobjects other than params seems to work ok.

Comment: mu: its already been asked there several times - I just ffelt like griping as it appears no one is actually interested in a solution

Comment: It seems that it is just the keys that are encoded if that helps.

Comment: What happens if you leave the UTF-8 checking `✓` out of `params`?

Comment: How would I remove the UTF-8 checking from params? Sorry I am a bit of a rails n00b

Comment: Try `dup`ing it and removing the appropriate key.

Comment: dup does not work sorry - I get !binary keys for objects that don't have a utf-8 element.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try changing from .dump to .inspect like this?

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

Comment: Thats much better, I'd still like to know why the keys in .dump are base64 encoded.

Comment: Just a note on the bounty - I will wait a few more days for someone to answer the question of why .dump is being encoded and how to fix it, but if no answer is forthcoming I will award it to this answer which is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thanks Chris! In case it helps to know, Rails sometimes stores hash keys as base64 because it's the most convenient way to store hash key blobs in a text field of a database. For example, the Rails default session store does automatic base64 encoding. I don't know if that's what's happening with your params, yet perhaps it's a lead for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the string encoding for the key which is oddly represented as `!binary` even though there are no non 7-bit ASCII characters in there. The values are encoded as base-64 to render them in plain-text:

```
"dXRmOA==".unpack('m')
# => ["utf8"]
```

This could be an artifact of your environment where the default string encoding is irregular.

Comment: My application.rb file has: config.encoding = "utf-8" There should be no non-utf-8 characters anywhere in the system. even if what you say is try, this doesn't help me get the actual data in a plaintext form.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely too late to help you, but hopefully others that are coming to this question while working through the Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorials may find it helpful.

The Rails Tutorials 2nd edition uses the sqlite3 1.3.5 gem.

This answer explains the differences of how the stuff parses out... [YAML output from rails console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050615/yaml-output-from-rails-console)

It worked for me -- I upgraded the sqlite3 gem to 1.3.6 in my Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and killed/restarted the rails server. After that, the !binary is changed back to the text-based keys you would expect.