# YAML output from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, yaml

When executing a command like `y Grau.all` in rails console I am getting these strange `!binary` strings instead of the attribute's name. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
irb(main):003:0> y Grau.all
  ←[1m←[36mGrau Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "graus".* FROM "gr
  ←[1m←[35mEXPLAIN (0.0ms)←[0m  EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT "grau

EXPLAIN for: SELECT "graus".* FROM "graus"
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE graus (~1000000 rows)

---
- !ruby/object:Grau
  attributes:
    !binary "aWQ=": 27
    !binary "bm9tZQ==": 1 Grau
    !binary "Y3JlYXRlZF9hdA==": 2012-04-06 21:24:34.553163000 Z
    !binary "dXBkYXRlZF9hdA==": 2012-04-06 21:24:34.553163000 Z
- !ruby/object:Grau
  attributes:
    !binary "aWQ=": 28
    !binary "bm9tZQ==": 2 Grau
    !binary "Y3JlYXRlZF9hdA==": 2012-04-06 21:24:34.599963000 Z
    !binary "dXBkYXRlZF9hdA==": 2012-04-06 21:24:34.599963000 Z
```

[UPDATES]

```
irb(main):001:0> Grau.find(1)
  ←[1m←[36mGrau Load (43.8ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "graus".* FROM "graus" WHERE "grau
s"."id" = ? LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Grau id: 1, nome: "1º Grau", created_at: "2012-04-11 15:51:32", updated_at:
 "2012-04-11 15:51:32">
irb(main):002:0>
```

I am using Rails 3.2.3, Ruby 1.9.3 on a Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Could you give an example of only one `Grau` object? What is the output in the console of `Grau.find(1)` (or any other valid ID)? Is it binary as well? What version of ruby and rails are you using?

Comment: updated question as requested. please take a look. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be because rails defaults to using the newer `psych` YAML engine, the older `syck` yaml engine doesn't output the `!binary` keys. If you're just wanting it for testing in the console you can switch back to the older yaml engine as a temp workaround:

```
 > y User.first
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  !binary "aWQ=": 1
  !binary "bmFtZQ==": Example User
  !binary "ZW1haWw=": user@example.com

 > YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
=> "syck"

 > y User.first
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  id: 1
  name: Example User
  email: user@example.com
```

You would only need to do this when your ActiveRecord column names/attributes keys are encoded using `Encoding::ASCII_8BIT` which I think only happens with SQLite.

---

### **Update:**

Since posting this answer the SQLite3 gem has been fixed to [return utf8 for column names](https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/commit/4a47171747beb938dcf6ff7e4bc5f42a1ed199c9). Make sure you're using version 1.3.6 (or higher) of the sqlite3 gem. Then the default/newer psych yaml engine (which also supports human-readable unicode output) will work without problems:

```
 > y User.first
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  EXPLAIN (0.0ms)  EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  LIMIT 1
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE users (~1000000 rows)

--- !ruby/object:User
attributes:
  id: 1
  name: irmão
  email: user@example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It works! Is there anyway to run that command to change yaml engine automatically or any configuration file I can change so that I don't have to do this manually everytime? Thanks.

Comment: Are you just wanting it in the rails console? If so, you could put `YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck' if defined?(Rails::Console)` in your `development.rb`

Comment: That does the trick. However, now, I am getting what I believe are unicode representation of some special characters like `irm\xC3\xA3o` instead of `irmão`. In a language like mine, Portuguese, it's rather important to be able to see these characters on the console. Any idea how to workaround this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was encountering the same issue with displaying my debug(params) on one of my pages.  It was frustrating me to no end.  I probably took the long way around, but I had been using sqlite3, and knowing that I was going to use Postgres in production, I went ahead and configured the Postgres database locally (Kind of a pain in the butt).
The other thing that might have done it was on the database.yml file I added 
**encoding: unicode**.

If you have the time and the patience it's probably best to use same database in test as you will use in production.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure irb, but try `rails console` inside your Rails application root (which will load all the activerecord objects correctly)

*In Rails 2.x*

```
<your rails app> ruby script/console
```

*In Rails 3.x*

```
<your rails app> rails c
```